# code-server installation issues on Mojave

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, homebrew, macos-mojave

I wanted to install code-server on my Macbook pro, mojave 10.14.6, following instructions provided here https://github.com/cdr/code-server/blob/master/doc/guide.md

While trying to install using given command: curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh I get following errors:

> macOS v10.14.6 Installing from Homebrew.
>
> - brew install code-server Error: No available formula with the name "code-server" 
>     ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)... Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run: 
>     git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
>
> Error: No previously deleted formula found.
>   ==> Searching for similarly named formulae... Error: No similarly named formulae found.
>   ==> Searching taps...
>   ==> Searching taps on GitHub... Error: No formulae found in taps.

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

`brew install code-server` should simply work.

installation log

```
$ brew install code-server
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/code-server-3.4.1_1.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/ed/eda0ef4457730392ec9fbd0354ef3c25e67d6c658563876837c16cc994200b02?__gda__=exp=159401120
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring code-server-3.4.1_1.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
The launchd service runs on http://127.0.0.1:8080. Logs are located at /usr/local/var/log/code-server.log.

To have launchd start code-server now and restart at login:
  brew services start code-server
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  code-server
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/code-server/3.4.1_1: 3,984 files, 167.0MB
```

test log

```
$ code-server --version
info  Wrote default config file to ~/.config/code-server/config.yaml
info  Using config file ~/.config/code-server/config.yaml
3.4.1 48f7c2724827e526eeaa6c2c151c520f48a61259
```